# Adding images to wordpress custom post type categories (taxonomy)

Tags: arrays, wordpress

I am trying to add images to categories in my WordPress theme. I added images to the categories. The image of the relevant category appears in the admin panel and in relevant places on the site. But I am getting this error from the code block in `function.php` file.

```
Warning: Undefined array key "category_custom_image_url" in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\customjob\functions.php on line 457
```

I couldn't identify the array element `'category_custom_image_url'` which was causing the error.

```
add_action( 'edit_term', 'edit_term_callback' );
    function edit_term_callback($term_id) {
        $image = '';
        $image = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'term_image' );
        if ( $image )
            update_term_meta( $term_id, 'term_image', esc_url( $_POST['category_custom_image_url']) )
    else
        add_term_meta( $term_id, 'term_image', esc_url( $_POST['category_custom_image_url']) );
}
```

**Edit:** I solved the undefined variable problem with this code:
`$_POST[] = 'category_custom_image_url';`
I put it on the line just before this line of code:
`if ( $image )`

**There is another problem;**

In the editing section, I can delete the image and add a new one. However, when I press the update button without doing anything, it deletes the current image. How can I keep the current image stable?

**problem solved**

I solved the problem this way. When we say update, we ask whether the query is empty or not. But we also need to say update or add if the posted image is not available. I missed this part. Naturally, since I haven't done this check, when I click update, it removes the image in the query. There is no problem for now. I'll update the question if I notice anything.

The code that provides the control is in the 4th line:

```
add_action( 'edit_term', 'edit_term_callback' );
function edit_term_callback($term_id) {
    $_POST[] = 'category_custom_image_url';
    if ( isset($_POST['category_custom_image_url']) && '' !== $_POST['category_custom_image_url'] )
    update_term_meta( $term_id, 'term_image', esc_url( $_POST['category_custom_image_url']) );
    else
    add_term_meta( $term_id, 'term_image', esc_url( $_POST['category_custom_image_url']) );
}
```

@womd Thank you very much for your interest. life be the way you want it to be.

Comment: How is this related to [tag:undef]? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why not check what `$_POST` contains?

Comment: $_POST['category_custom_image_url'] = $image;
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image(array('category_custom_image_url'));

  Different results are obtained with . I applied these two methods and a few methods that I didn't note before, but I can't identify the array.

Comment: As you can see after having dumped `$_POST`, the array key you want to access is not set

Answer (score 0):

ok, so what about this:

```
add_action( 'edit_term', 'edit_term_callback' );

function edit_term_callback($term_id) {
$image = get_term_meta($term_id, 'term_image', true);

if(isset($_POST['category_custom_image_url']) ){

    if ($image) {
        update_term_meta($term_id, 'term_image', esc_url($_POST['category_custom_image_url']));
    } else {
        add_term_meta($term_id, 'term_image', esc_url($_POST['category_custom_image_url']));
    }
}
}
```

where did you put:

```
$_POST[] = 'category_custom_image_url';
```

? this is no real fix.

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you and Nico. I solved this problem this way. `$_POST[] = 'category_custom_image_url';
    return $_POST;`  Your solution works too. But when I press the update button without taking any action, the current image is deleted. Is the image deletion issue related to this?

Comment: i wonder if that works as expected ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that all clarification should be added **to your question**, not to any comment section

Comment: **@womd** Thank you very much for your interest. When I press the update button directly without any intervention, the current image is deleted. Or when I press the delete button, the current image is not deleted. I fix one and the other one breaks. I can't fix two errors at the same time.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it

Comment: unfortunately your last code does not add images to the category. I select the image and press save. After refreshing the page the image area is empty. It does not send images to the page either. When you make the following correction in your code, it loads the image.3. I added it to the line. ($image = ' ';) but when I press the update button for the second time, the image is deleted. The picture doesn't hold up. I think the update button affects it and resets it.

Comment: @womd my problem solved. for all thank you